# WooCommerce featured product change hook

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to hook my custom function whenever any product assigned as featured product or removed from featured product.

I have found that featured product call WC_AJAX on WooCommerce and it don't have any action hook.

Class `WC_AJAX woocommerce/includes/class-wc-ajax.php`  line 505

```
/**
 * Toggle Featured status of a product from admin.
 */
public static function feature_product() {
    if ( current_user_can( 'edit_products' ) && check_admin_referer( 'woocommerce-feature-product' ) && isset( $_GET['product_id'] ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( absint( $_GET['product_id'] ) );

        if ( $product ) {
            $product->set_featured( ! $product->get_featured() );
            $product->save();
        }
    }

    wp_safe_redirect( wp_get_referer() ? remove_query_arg( array( 'trashed', 'untrashed', 'deleted', 'ids' ), wp_get_referer() ) : admin_url( 'edit.php?post_type=product' ) );
    exit;
}
```

---

Any advice how can i hook my custom function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [woocommerce/includes/class-wc-ajax.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/1947c80c219d40b23c01580467ea4b0fa0d8076f/includes/class-wc-ajax.php) from line 122 ... 179 it says:

```php
$ajax_events = array(
    'feature_product',
    'mark_order_status',
    ...
);

foreach ( $ajax_events as $ajax_event ) {
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_woocommerce_' . $ajax_event, array( __CLASS__, $ajax_event ) );
}
```

---

So with that knowledge **we can assign our custom function to the hook**

```php
function my_callback_function () {
    // Do something
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_woocommerce_feature_product', 'my_callback_function', 5 );
```

---

> **Explanation**
>
> **Point 1**
>
> Hook priority of **5** used - **for this ajax call our action has to come before the woocommerce action because the woocommerce action does a redirect**.
>
> The **default** priority is **10**
>
> ---
>
> **Point 2**
>
> `wp_ajax_`
>
> This hook allows you to create custom handlers for your own custom
> AJAX requests. The `wp_ajax_` hook follows the format
> `wp_ajax_$youraction`, where `$youraction` is your AJAX request’s
> ‘action’ property.
>
> The `wp_ajax_` hook only fires for logged-in users.
>
> If you need to also listen for Ajax requests that don’t come from
> logged-in users.
>
> `wp_ajax_nopriv_`
>
> This hook is functionally the same as `wp_ajax_(action)`, however it is
> used to handle AJAX requests on the front-end for unauthenticated
> users, i.e. when `is_user_logged_in()` returns false. Unlike
> `wp_ajax_(action)` the ajaxurl javascript global property will not be
> automatically defined and must be included manually or by using
> `wp_localize_script()` with `admin_url( ‘admin-ajax.php’ )` as the data.
>
> Source: https://jaydeepchauhanblog.wordpress.com/2017/07/14/wordpress-main-different-between-wp_ajax-and-wp_ajax_nopriv/

Comment: It fires before featured assigned/unassigned operation of product. However I found a way for my task using this hook.

Comment: @VickyP _"It fires before"_. see point 1 in the attached explanation in my answer why